# Does SU(3) have a representation in geometric algebra?

Tags: group-theory, geometric-algebras

Both geometric algebras and SU(3) have matrix representations. which geometric algebra has the same matrix representation as SU(3)?

Comment: $SU(n)$ is not a linear space (the sum of two special-unitary matrices is not special-unitary), while a geometric algebra is a linear space.

Comment: I think $SU(n)$ is (isomorphic to) the set of all rotations in $\mathbb R^{2n}$ that preserve the bivector $$J=e_1e_2+e_3e_4+\cdots+e_{2n-1}e_{2n}.$$ A rotation can be represented by a rotor $R$, and preserving $J$ means $RJR^\sim=J$, or $RJ=JR$. See also "[Lie Groups as Spin Groups](http://geocalc.clas.asu.edu/pdf/LGasSG.pdf)". But it looks like you're not asking about this.

Comment: What do you mean by "the same matrix representation"?